# How to Handle WPF grid in QTP 9.2.?

Tags: wpf, qtp

Looks like QTP 9.2 is not 100% compatible with WPF. I wish to read the data from WPF grid, but it takes as an individual object and intermittently crashes.

Any help would be useful.

Comment: 9.2 is quite an old version (since then 9.5, 10 and 11 have been released). Do you know if the behaviour is any better in newer versions?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have full control over how values are extracted from Wpf object using QTP requires writing a small custom library to which qtp objects are passed as MarshalByRef objects. I've wrote a post describing it in short detail
[here](http://www.advancedqtp.com/forums/index.php/topic,3320.0.html)

We first started using it with QTP 9.2 and successfully migrated to 10.

Once written, this solution would satisfy any need regarding running QTP on WPF.

If you have any implementation specific question feel free to email me